# Printout sequence in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7

```
def foo(num,base):
    if(num>= base):
        foo(num/base,base)
    print num%base,num
 numA =126
 numB = 2
foo(numA,numB)
```

In my mind,

[image]

results should be same as picture 1. However, when I run the code, it comes out as:

[image].

First line is 1,1. Why? 
The condition fulfill the loop, and it should print 1,63 in the first line and 1,31 in the second line. Meanwhile, why 0, 126 prints at last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think what you intended was something like below, 1st iteration will taking input 126, subsequence will be num/base

```
def foo(num,base):
    print num%base,num
    if(num>= base):
        foo(num/base,base)
```

Comment: addon, the question title is a bit inappropriate, probably change to something like question on recursive function call

Comment: I change the code according to your answer, and I understand the results, however, I am still curious about my code. I cannot understand clearly. Would please explain for me, I am just a green hand in python.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand what you explain. According to your answer, the results should be (1,63)(1,31)....(1,1)(0,126). However, when I run the code, it came out (1,1)(1,3)...(1,63)(0,126). That's the thing I still cannot understand.

Comment: actually there is mistake in my previous explanation, it should be as below.With input num 126 and base 2, you intended to get result in iteration as 126%2, 63%2, 31%2, 15%2, 7%2, 3%2, 1%2. But for your code, it will be execute in iteration 1%2, 3%2, 7%2, 15%2, 31%2, 63%2, 126%2

Comment: During 1st iteration, input num 126 and base 2, so it will execute code inside if block which recursively call itself with input num 63,31,15,7,3,1, recursive call ends at 1 where the if condition break, and it execute next line "print num%base, num, which print out 1 1. Then the recursive call return 1 by 1 in order (1,3), (1,7), (1,15), (1,31), (1,63), (1,126)